# HTML5 CSS3 LAYOUT

Tags: html, css

I am beginner in web design and i have a problem with fixing the layout of my webpage. I want to make a two column content area with aside element but i can not find the right way. I have tried to reduce the width of section but it did not work. Can someone tell me a good option about my css code? Thanks!

```
article, aside, footer, header, main, nav, section{
    display: block;
}
#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 96%; /* Holding outermost DIV */
}
#header {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-color: #165E00;
    width:1000px;
    color:white;  
    padding:10px;    
}
strong text
#section {
    margin-left:156px;
    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    background-color:#FFDD00;
    height:1900px;
    width:1000px;
    padding:10px;   
    text-align: justify;    
}
```

Comment: Is "strong text" literally there in your CSS file?  Literally, what that line is saying is a item with the id "section" which is inside of a `<text>` tag, which in turn is inside of a `<strong>` tag.

Comment: @Antreas.b Ive updated my answer to be a little more informative. Its obvious you are very new to this and as much as Bootstrap or other frameworks might speed things up for you I really would suggest getting to grips with the fundamentals of HTML and CSS before looking to use a framework or flexbox etc. Please can you provide your HTML and ill gladly try and help you along a little further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my suggestion for you when you want to create columns with pure [HTML5/CSS3](http://codepen.io/starlight-tu/pen/LVGjeB): [Yep, the 'flex' CSS3 property]

```css
body, main, header, nav,
div, section, aside, article,
img, p, code, ul, ol,
a, span, del, strong {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', 'Segoe UI';
 font-weight: lighter
}

body {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 margin: 0
}

main {
 display: flex;
 align-items: flex-start;
 justify-content: space-around;
 padding: 3% 4%;
 height: 100%; width: 100%;
}

.col {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 height: 100%; width: 40%;
}

.content {
 text-indent: 25pt;
 text-align: justify;
}

.credit {
 margin-top: 5pt;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <aside class='col'>
  <h2>Header of column left</h2>
  <article class='content'>
   Đây là cách mà chúng ta tạo cột với HTML5/CSS3. Như bạn có thể thấy, thuộc tính 'flex' (mền dẻo) thực sự mạnh mẽ. Nó không chỉ giúp bạn tạo cột một cách dễ dàng mà còn giúp bạn rất nhiều trong việc canh chỉ các phần tử như mình đang làm đây.
  </article>
  <footer class='credit'>By: <a href='https://www.facebook.com/starlight.tu'>Nguyễn Đăng Tú</a></footer>
 </aside>
 <aside class='col'>
  <h2>Header of column right</h2>
  <article class='content'>
   This is the way how we create columns in HTML5/CSS3. As you can see, the 'flex' property is so powerful. It's not only help you make columns so easy but also help you a lot in align the elements like the I do.
  </article>
  <footer class='credit'>By: <a href='starlight2014.wordpress.com'>Star Light</a></footer>
 </aside>
</main>
```

I hope that what you are looking for.

Comment: Flexbox is being used far too much at the moment, cross browser compatibility is still important and should be considered, as suggested by @DJDavid98. Using flexbox for what a very simple `float` can achieve seems overkill and shortsighted, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure what are you talking about but `flex` is good on [FF](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and Cr. I've already tried it, it works miracle.

Answer (score 2):

For websites using columns in such a manner i recommend checking out a responsive/fluid grid system such as bootstrap, foundation, skeleton, etc

Comment: Generally I would agree however it is worth learning how and why this works. Frameworks are great but you should encourage people to learn the fundamentals of development before encouraging the use of pre-compiled frameworks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
article, aside, footer, header, main, nav, section{
    /* It looks like you're confusing ID's with HTML5 tags */
    display: block;
}

#wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
    width: 96%; /* Holding outermost DIV */
}

#header {
    color:white;  
    background-color: #165E00;
    width:100%; /* Using fixed widths inside a fluid element will give you a hard time. */
    /* Padding and Margin (and borders) add to the width, be careful */
 }

/* strong text - this "strong text" is errornous */
#section {
    /* margin-left:156px; - not like this. Use a float. */
    float:left;
    width: 70%;

    font-family: Sans-Serif;
    background-color:#FFDD00;
    text-align: justify; 

    /* remove default padding and margin, research "Eric Meyer, CSS Reset" */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}

#aside { 
    float:left;
    width:30%;

    /* remove default padding and margin, research "Eric Meyer, CSS Reset" */
    margin:0;
    padding:0;   
}
```

- Note: Please provide your HTML. It's hard to tell if you have used # incorrectly or if you're specifying the ID in the HTML correctly.
- Note: You're using a mixture of fixed and relative values for widths which isnt helping you either.

You should read about CSS floats. You can `float` elements such as `<div>` tags next to each other with a CSS float.

**See:**

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score -3):

For columns, use a table (http://www.w3schools.com/Html/html_tables.asp)! it is much more easier. Also, I would recommend looking into bootstrap, it will make your web-application compatible for all screens including that of mobile devices.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YXVoqJEwqoQ&spfreload=10

Goodluck!

Comment: Tables are most certainly not the way to go about anything structural in web design, the only exception is when displaying tabular data. Please dont use tables for structure!

Comment: Tables are for tabular data and not layouts.